# WPF DataTrigger with OpacityMask

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, visualbrush, opacitymask

i´m using Mahapps.Metro and want to change an icon depending on an Property.

[Here is the Mahapps sample for their Icons](http://mahapps.com/guides/icons-and-resources.html)

Setting only the Backgroundcolor("Fill") of the rectangle everything works fine. As soon as the OpacityMask is set the complete rectangle stays blank.

```xml
<Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOnline}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                    <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_disconnect}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOnline}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_connect}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Any ideas what i do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long time i found a working solution for me:

- The first problem was the missing Ressource BlackBrush which is used
  inside the Icons.xaml
- And the trick for the is replacing the whole Rectangle. I took an ContentControl for this job

---

```
<ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOnline}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Content" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="20" Height="20">
                                        <Rectangle.Resources>
                                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Black" />
                                        </Rectangle.Resources>
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_disconnect}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOnline}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Content" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="20">
                                        <Rectangle.Resources>
                                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Black" />
                                        </Rectangle.Resources>
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_connect}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
```